# Rails: Setting a value to input field if variable exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm trying to set a value to two text field inputs when an id is passed to the new action in the controller. The current code works but I'm wondering if the code can be shortened.

**Current code**

View

```
<div class="custom-input">
  <% if @debtor %>
    <input type="text" name="debtor_name" class="form-control" id="debtor-search-form" value='<%= @debtor.name %>'>
  <% else %>
    <input type="text" name="debtor_name" class="form-control" id="debtor-search-form">
  <% end %>
</div>
<% if @debtor %>
  <%= f.text_field :debtor_id, class: "form-control", value: @debtor.id %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.text_field :debtor_id, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

I tried removing the if-else part to make the code shorter

**Shorter code**

View

```
<div class="custom-input">
    <input type="text" name="debtor_name" class="form-control" id="debtor-search-form" value='<%= @debtor.name if @debtor %>'>
</div>
<%= f.text_field :debtor_id, class: "form-control", value: @debtor.id if @debtor %>
```

When no debtor is passed, the shortened code results to the first input having a "hanging" value tag (i.e. it just shows value. no equal sign after it)

```
<input type="text" name="debtor_name" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="debtor-search-form" value autocomplete="off">
```

while the second input disappears.

Is a "hanging" value tag ok? I inspected the html and the "hanging" value tag resolves to value="" if i click 'edit as html'

Is there a way to shorten the code or should i just stick with it?

Comment: Is this part of a form or just an `input` field without a `form`?

Comment: @ABMagil yup part of a form. just took the part which im trying to shorten

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having an HTML attribute as just `value` is fine, in HTML5. Also, the *raw* HTML source code probably reads as `value=''`, judging by your `html.erb` code.
I guess that you're using Chrome's or Firefox's developer tools, that will try to *correct* and format odd looking HTML for you, and will probably display it without the empty `=''`.

Then, the problem with this:

```
<%= f.text_field :debtor_id, class: "form-control", value: @debtor.id if @debtor %>
```

Is operator precedence. Your `if` applies to the whole statement.
Try with:

```
<%= f.text_field :debtor_id, class: "form-control", value: (@debtor.id if @debtor) %>
```

Or:

```
<%= f.text_field :debtor_id, class: "form-control", value: @debtor.try!(:id) %>
```

Comment: never thought parentheses in "value:" would solve that and that "try" would work even if @debtor is not defined. cool.

Comment: That's because `@instance` variables default to `nil`, and ActiveSupport adds `NilClass#try`.

Answer (score 1):

The hanging value tag doesn't make a difference. As you saw yourself, it's the same as `value=""`, which is the "default" value. It is also completely valid HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try [try object](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)

```
<div class="custom-input">      
  <input type="text" name="debtor_name" class="form-control" id="debtor-search-form" value='<%= @debtor.try(:name) %>'>
</div>
<%= f.text_field :debtor_id, class: "form-control", value: @debtor.try(:id) %>
```